# Angular CLI gives me "TypeError: callbacks[i] is not a function" when I "ng serve"

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular-cli

I literally just made a fresh installation of the Angular CLI in order to try it out and I don't have a clue on what's causing the following error on the command line:

```
    PC:cobros Fran$ ng serve
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
 95% emitting/Users/Fran/Documents/Workspace/Repos/cobros/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:40
        callbacks[i](err, result);
                    ^

TypeError: callbacks[i] is not a function
    at Storage.finished (/Users/Fran/Documents/Workspace/Repos/cobros/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:40:15)
    at /Users/Fran/Documents/Workspace/Repos/cobros/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:77:9
    at /Users/Fran/Documents/Workspace/Repos/cobros/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:287:18
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:5)
```

This is the information I get returned when I try "ng -v" (In case it's useful at all):

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.8
Node: 8.9.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.2.4
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.42
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.29
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.52
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.8
@schematics/angular: 0.1.17
typescript: 2.5.3
webpack: 3.10.0
```

What does the 'enhanced-resolve' module even do?
Did I install angular wrong? I followed the instructions from https://github.com/angular/angular-cli and made sure I fulfilled the prerequisites.

Comment: Yesterday I created an app with the CLI and it worked, I tried a new one again  and this time it crashed, I'm thinking some update happened, maybe this is helpful for someone to help us

Comment: Happened to me today after upgrading @angular to latest(5.2.4) and cli to 1.6.8. Link to cli 1.6.8 release(no breaking change mentioned) https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases/tag/v1.6.8

Comment: Lol I guess I just picked the worst moment to try the Angular CLI out

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9550

Comment: Then I guess whoever says "It's a known error" along with instructions on how to downgrade this thing gets the top answer.

Comment: Same here yesterday it worked but today I m also getting same error.

Comment: worked perfectly yesterday but not today :(

Comment: setting `"@angular/cli": "1.6.7"` didn't work. Seems to be ng webpack

Comment: They probably updated this "enhanced-resolve" and now it doesn't work..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

EDIT: The issue is now fixed, so there is no need to use this workaround anymore.

---

Solution (workaround) found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9550#issuecomment-364092554)

Add `"copy-webpack-plugin": "4.3.0"` to your package.json

Thanks @neshkatrapati

Comment: npm install copy-webpack-plugin@4.3.0

Comment: Must be done after installation of cli - in my instance, but yes works.

Comment: It is also true angular-cli 1.3 versions work with the copy-webpack change, however I can imagine for many that's not a solution.

Comment: dont use the workaround, it resolved now by the Angular team.

Comment: It seems they fixed it, I just tested creating an app from scratch using CLI and works fine

Answer (score 7):

I had same problem and this command did miracle for me

```
npm install copy-webpack-plugin@4.3.1
```

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**: The issue is now fixed, so there is no need to use this workaround anymore.

---

Happens after upgrading `@angular/cli` to `1.6.8`.

**Solution**: Problem is with `copy-webpack-plugin` (https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin/issues/217)
`npm i copy-webpack-plugin@4.3.1 --save-dev` helps

**NOTE**: Previous offered solution was to downgrade cli to 1.6.7, which does not help.

Answer (score 5):

This issue should now be resolved with v4.4.1 released just now. 
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin/releases/tag/v4.4.1

Answer (score 1):

As stated here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9550 it's a problem with copy-webpack-plugin.

It can be solved by doing `npm install copy-webpack-plugin@4.3.0`

Answer (score 0):

Following github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9550 (thanks @oers for the link in the comments)

<del>I just downgraded Anuglar CLI to version 1.6.7.</del>

<del>To do so, just type</del>

<del>`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`</del>

<del>And once it finished install a previous version</del>

<del>`npm install -g @angular/cli@1.6.7`</del>

<del>**NOTE**: This will work but it is just a temporary solution, they probably -and hopefully- hot fix this.</del>

**EDIT**: Actually I tried the wrong project which wasn't using CLI, tried again and it doesn't work, if you follow the github thread, it looks like a big thing, as it doesn't work with CLI 1.5.x nor 1.6.x (didn't tried with the others). It looks like the only thing we can do ATM is either debug through or sit and wait.

OOPS!

Comment: you probably have a typo there - you are uninstalling twice

Comment: This didn't work for me, have I missed a trick or that is the case for everyone?

Comment: It doesn't work, see the edit (that's why I cancelled your Edit, I already had editted it before you submitted your edit, but thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Just execute `yarn upgrade`.

There was a release of *copy_webpack_plugin* fixing the bug (4.4.1), so this should be preferred for resolving this issue. With npm, `npm --depth 9999 update` should do the trick to update all dependencies recursively.

Regarding the *depth* argument for npm update:

> As of npm@2.6.1, the npm update will only inspect top-level packages. Prior versions of npm would also recursively inspect all dependencies. To get the old behavior, use npm --depth 9999 update

Original answer below:

### Solution

```
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm i copy-webpack-plugin@4.3.1 -E -O
npm i
```

**Explanation**:

- We remove *node_modules* and lockfile
- We specify *copy_webpack_plugin* only as a peer dependency (option `-O`) and with an exact version (option `-E`)
- We install *node_modules*

Answer (score 0):

if npm install copy-webpack-plugin@4.3.1 doesn`t help try add in package.json:

"optionalDependencies": {
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.3.1"
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try this command -> npm install copy-webpack-plugin@4.3.0 resolved my issue

Answer (score -2):

run this command npm install copy-webpack-plugin@4.3.0

Answer (score -2):

callbacks[i](err, result);
                            ^

TypeError: callbacks[i] is not a function

solution:-
npm install copy-webpack-plugin@4.3.0

Answer (score -4):

Try to uninstall and reinstall Angular CLI :

Global package:

`npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
if npm version is > 5 then use`npm cache verify`to avoid errors (or to avoid using --force)
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Local project package:

`rm -rf node_modules dist # use rmdir /S/Q node_modules dist in Windows Command Prompt; use rm -r -fo node_modules,dist in Windows PowerShell
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
npm install`

Comment: Still brokerino

Comment: Did not help. I had to downgrade to 1.6.7 until the issue is fixed by AngularCli team (see https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9550).